# Does this.forceUpdate rerender all children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The documents have the following to say about forceUpdate:

> Calling forceUpdate() will cause render() to be called on the
>   component, skipping shouldComponentUpdate(). This will trigger the
>   normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the
>   shouldComponentUpdate() method of each child. React will still only
>   update the DOM if the markup changes.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Does this mean that children of the component also have their render function called?

Comment: Yes, except if their `shouldComponentUpdate` decides that re-rendering is not necessairy. `forceUpdate` will only bypass `shouldComponentUpdate` on the component on which `forceUpdate` is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will "re-render" every child that does not return false inside of its `shouldComponentUpdate` method, however note that `re-rendering !== re-drawing`, it will just cause React's diffing algorithm to run.

And only, if the diffing algorithm sees a difference in the current version of the virtual DOM compared to the previous version of the virtual DOM will the specific "changed" part of the UI get re-drawn on the screen.